# How you change the button color?

Tags: html

Hellow,i am a biginner in html and i have a question. I  want to change the button collor in my web site and i dont know how to do it.

I tried many sources in the internet but nothing worked.

Comment: Hello, watch some tutorials on HTML and CSS, there're lots of them online. Furthermore, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), and read up on [asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). After doing some research and [searching](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, try it yourself. If you're stuck, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and note exactly where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend the same as what @Shakepear said, [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/) is a great place to start and in their [CSS tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp) you can find everything.
That being said what you want to do is either set the `background-color` or the font `color`, which can be done as follows:

```css
.rw {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

.bo {
  background-color: blue;
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<p><button class="rw">red and white</button></p>
<p><button class="bo">blue and orange</button></p>
```

By the way, it really helps if you show us some of your code next time so we know what you've tried